# Worlds not visible between users

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I copied worlds from a Kindle Fire to a new one. Unfortunately, I can't see the worlds from my son's (Kindle for Kids) account. According to what I saw here in other questions, I'm supposed to be able to see the worlds between users.

I can see them in my account though, so I suspect a permission issue, but the Mojang support is completely useless.

Any ideas as to what I need to change in the setup?